# Flutter - Validation error message is displaying inside textbox

Tags: android, react-native, android-studio, flutter

I am creating a login page. In that i trying to display error validation message as Invalid email if the email is not in proper format. Problem is , Error message is displaying inside the textbox and the textbox size is extending if the error message is displaying

```
      TextFormField(
      controller: emailController,
      autocorrect: true,
      validator: (value) {
        if (value.isEmpty) {
          return 'Please enter your credential';
        } else if (userExistR == false) {
          return "Email ID not registered";
        }
        return null;
      },
      decoration: InputDecoration(
        // helperText: " ",
        contentPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
            vertical: (snapshot.hasData) ? 24 : 18, horizontal: 15.0),
        prefixIcon: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsetsDirectional.only(end: 8.0),
          child: Icon(Icons.email),
        ),
        labelText: "Email address",
        hintText: 'xxxxx@xxx.xx',
        fillColor: Colors.white,
        enabledBorder: const OutlineInputBorder(
          borderSide:
              const BorderSide(color: Colors.transparent, width: 0.0),
        ),
        focusedBorder: const OutlineInputBorder(
          borderSide:
              const BorderSide(color: Colors.transparent, width: 0.0),
        ),
        errorBorder: const OutlineInputBorder(
          borderSide:
              const BorderSide(color: Colors.transparent, width: 0.0),
        ),
        border: new OutlineInputBorder(
            borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(15.0),
            borderSide: new BorderSide(color: Colors.blueGrey)),
        errorText: validateEmail(emailController.text),
      ),
      keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
      maxLines: 1,
      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16.0),
    );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You create use a custom TextField with the help of stack, here is one I use:

```
Stack(
    alignment: Alignment.bottomLeft,
    children: <Widget>[
      TextField(
        textAlignVertical: TextAlignVertical.center,
        controller: controller,
        decoration: InputDecoration(
          hintText: hintText,
          suffixIcon: icon != null
              ? IconButton(
                  icon: icon,
                  onPressed: onTapIcon,
                )
              : null,
          border: InputBorder.none,
        ),
      ),
      _handleError(context)
    ],
  )
```

where `_handleError` is

```
Widget _handleError(BuildContext context) {
if (errorText == null) {
  return Container();
}

return Container(
  padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 16, right: 16),
  child: Text(
    errorText,
    style: Theme.of(context)
        .textTheme
        .caption
        .copyWith(color: Theme.of(context).errorColor),
    maxLines: 1,
    overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
  ),
);
```

}

Comment: text box width is fixed now, But the error message is coming inside textbox.

Comment: set errorStyle: TextStyle(height: 0) to InputDecoration of your textFormField. This will hide the default error msg. Then use @Payam Asefi 's answer to display 'errorText' wherever you want to display the error. Hope this helps